# Laravel Eloquent Postgresql Select with Case and then filter by Case result

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a CASE raw statement that generates a status for each row. I want to filter by this status should the user not want to see all items but a specific set.

```php
$query = Device::leftJoin('devices_meters', 'devices_meters.device_id', '=', 'devices.id')
    ->leftJoin('device_measurements', 'device_measurements.device_id', '=', 'devices.id')
    ->select(
        'devices.*',
        DB::raw("
            CASE
                WHEN
                    devices.retired = false
                    AND devices.last_reported_utc_at > :dateFilter
                    AND SUM(device_measurements.flow) > 0
                THEN 'active'
                WHEN
                    devices.retired = false
                    AND devices.last_reported_utc_at > :dateFilter
                    AND SUM(device_measurements.flow) = 0
                THEN 'online'
                WHEN
                    devices.retired = false
                    AND devices.last_reported_utc_at <= :dateFilter
                THEN 'offline'
                WHEN
                    devices.retired = false
                    AND devices.serial_number IS NULL
                THEN 'inactive'
                WHEN
                    devices.retired = true
                THEN 'retired'
            END AS status,
            MAX(devices_meters.activated_at) AS activated_at,
            MAX(devices_meters.created_at) AS latest
        "),
    )
    ->setBindings(['dateFilter' => $dateFilter]);
    ->groupBy('devices.id', 'devices_meters.activated_at')
    ->orderBy('devices.installed_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate($user->settings_pagination);
```

I have tried:

```php
$query->where('status', '=', $status);
```

```php
$query->having('status', '=', $status);
```

But these do not work. What is the way by which I can filter by the `status` column?

Answer (score 0):

Since `status` is not really a column, you just need to use the whole case statement to filter.

If `$status`  is `active', then you'd need to add

```sql
WHERE (
    devices.retired = false
    AND devices.last_reported_utc_at > :dateFilter
    AND SUM(device_measurements.flow) > 0
)
```

to the SQL query and so on for every status.

Using Eloquent however, you can [define local query scopes in your `Device` model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Device extends Model
{
    public function scopeActive(Builder $query, $dateFilter)
    {
        $hasNecessaryJoins = collect($query->getQuery()->joins)
                             ->contains('table', 'device_measurements');

        return $query
            ->unless($hasNecessaryJoins, function ($subquery) {
                // do the left Join if it's not done already
                $subquery->leftJoin('device_measurements', 'device_measurements.device_id', '=', 'devices.id'));
            })
            ->where(function($subquery) use ($dateFilter) {
                $subquery->where('retired', false)
                         ->where('last_reported_utc_at', '>', $dateFilter)
                         ->whereRaw('SUM(device_measurements.flow) > 0');
            });
    }

    public function scopeOnline(Builder $query, $dateFilter)
    {
        // online seems to be the same as active?
        return $query
            ->active($dateFilter);           
    }

    public function scopeOffline(Builder $query, $dateFilter)
    {
        return $query
            ->where(function($subquery) use ($dateFilter) {
                $subquery->where('retired', false)
                         ->where('last_reported_utc_at', '<=', $dateFilter);
            });
    }

    public function scopeInactive(Builder $query, $dateFilter)
    {
        return $query
            ->where(function($subquery) {
                $subquery->where('retired', false)
                         ->whereNull('serial_number');
            });
    }

    public function scopeRetired(Builder $query, $dateFilter)
    {
        return $query
            ->where('retired', true);
    }
}
```

With these scopes in place, you can call `$query->active($dateFilter)`, `$query->online($dateFilter)`, `$query->offline($dateFilter)`, `$query->inactive($dateFilter)`, `$query->retired($dateFilter)`.

So if you have `$status = 'active'` you could call `$query->$status($dateFilter)`;